# Change jsp on button click

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a question.

I have 3 jsp page.
The first is a menu with 2 button.
When I click the first button I want to open the second jsp page.
When I click the second button I want to open the third jsp page.

Can you help me? I must use a servlet(it's not a problem, i know it)?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
 <body>
    <form name="TrainerMenu" action="TrainerMenu" method="get">

       <h1>Benvenuto in LESSON! Scegli l'operazione da effettuare:</h1>
       <input type="button" value="Creazione Nuovo Corso" name="CreateCourse" />
       <input type="button" value="Gestione Autorizzazioni"
        name="AuthorizationManager" />

    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have several options, I'll start from the easiest:

1- Change the input buttons to links, you can style them with css so they look like buttons:

```
<a href="CreateCourse.jsp">Creazione Nuovo Corso</a>
```

instead of

```
<input type="button" value="Creazione Nuovo Corso" name="CreateCourse" />
```

2- Use javascript to change the action of the form depending on the button you click:

```
<input type="button" value="Creazione Nuovo Corso" name="CreateCourse" 
onclick="document.forms[0].action = 'CreateCourse.jsp'; return true;" />
```

3- Use a servlet or JSP to handle the request and redirect or forward to the appropriate JSP page.

Answer (score 5):

You could make those submit buttons and inside the servlet your are submitting the form to you could test the name of the button which was pressed and render the corresponding jsp page.

```
<input type="submit" value="Creazione Nuovo Corso" name="CreateCourse" />
<input type="submit" value="Gestione Autorizzazioni" name="AuthorizationManager" />
```

Inside the `TrainerMenu` servlet if `request.getParameter("CreateCourse")` is not empty then the first button was clicked and you could render the corresponding jsp.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way you can do this is to use java script.
For example, `<input type="button" value="load" onclick="window.location='userpage.jsp'" >`

Answer (score 2):

If all you are looking for is navigation to page 2 and 3 from page one, replace the buttons with anchor elements as below:

```
<form name="TrainerMenu" action="TrainerMenu" method="get">

<h1>Benvenuto in LESSON! Scegli l'operazione da effettuare:</h1>
<a href="Page2.jsp" id="CreateCourse" >Creazione Nuovo Corso</a>&nbsp;
<a href="Page3.jsp" id="AuthorizationManager">Gestione Autorizzazioni</a>
<input type="button" value="" name="AuthorizationManager" />
</form>
```

If for some reason you need to use buttons, try this:

```
<form name="TrainerMenu" action="TrainerMenu" method="get">

   <h1>Benvenuto in LESSON! Scegli l'operazione da effettuare:</h1>
   <input type="button" value="Creazione Nuovo Corso" name="CreateCourse"
    onclick="openPage('Page2.jsp')"/>
   <input type="button" value="Gestione Autorizzazioni" name="AuthorizationManager"
    onclick="openPage('Page3.jsp')" />

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function openPage(pageURL)
 {
 window.location.href = pageURL;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use two forms.

In the first form action attribute will have name of the second jdp page and your 1st button. In the second form there will be 2nd button with action attribute thats giving the name of your 3rd jsp page.

It will be like this :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="main1"  method="get" action="2nd.jsp">
        <input type="submit" name="ter" value="LOGOUT" >
    </form>
    <DIV ALIGN="left"><form name="main0" action="3rd.jsp" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="FEEDBACK">
    </form></DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do with a button click and not the other way. You can do it by adding `location.href` to your button. Here is how I'm using

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="submit" onclick="location.href ='/dashboard'" >Go To Dashboard</button>
```

The button above uses bootstrap classes for styling. Without styling, the simplest code would be

```
<button onclick="location.href ='/dashboard'" >Go To Dashboard</button>
```

The `/dashboard` is my JSP page, If you are using extension too then used `/dashboard.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

It works using ajax.
The jsp then display in iframe returned by controller in response to request.

```
function openPage() {
  jQuery.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  data : jQuery(this).serialize(),
  url : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/post_action',
  success : function(data, textStatus) {
  jQuery('#iframeId').contents().find('body').append(data);
  },
  error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you put -- action = "submit"
inside of the button

Comment: This is merely a comment than an answer. Maybe you can explain a bit on what you would suggest as solution (instead of `action="submit"`).